# Add new columns from ssas to Power BI after deplyment

Tags: powerbi, ssas, dashboard, ssas-tabular

I have a SSAS tabular model I have deployed and made some power Bi reports. now I need to add some new columns and measures to SSAS and also add them to power BI. How I can do that?

Comment: This question is _far_ too broad for Stack Overflow.  Work your way through some tutorials (such as [this one from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tutorial-tabular-1400/as-adventure-works-tutorial?view=asallproducts-allversions)) and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

As Power BI connects to SSAS Tabular in Live Connection Mode, once you update the Data Model and deploy it, open Power BI Desktop and it should see the changes made on that connected SSAS Data Model. You can then update and publish your Power BI reports to the service so the new metadata takes affect.

Anything that you remove that from the Data Model, may introduce broken visuals and errors, however adding anything new that isn't yet used will not affect the visuals or reports.

Comment: I cannot use Live connect because it says the database local host does not have the model but when I use import It can find the model. so use import

Comment: If you importing you are not bring in any measures etc, just the data. Add them in Power BI like you would with SSAS Tabular. Power BI is a cut down version of SSAS Tabular it the same syntax

Comment: Thanks for your response. can you help me why I cannot use Live connect?

Comment: I would open another question for that issue with live connection, it could be a setting on the SSAS side

Comment: Thank you. can you give me the link?